# ¿Como obtener dato de una celda seleccionada en datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, .net, poo

Tengo un *Datagridview* llamado *dgv*, en el evento *doubleclick* de este *dgv *necesito obtener el valor esa celda donde hice *dobleclick*, el nombre de la columna donde está esa celda y el valor de la primer fila donde está esa celda.
Adjunto una imagen para explicarme mejor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener el valor de la celda seleccionada en este caso sería la palabra "RESERVADO", también necesito obtener el nombre de esa columna en este caso "mié. 13 sept." y obtener el valor de la primer columna de esta fila para este caso sería "11:30".

Espero me puedan ayudar. 
Gracias

Comment: En principio lo que quieres es muy sencillo,el propio evento te envía que celda lo levantó. Has intentado algo? Donde te has atascado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si analizas la documentacion del evento

[DataGridView.CellDoubleClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

veras dos argumentos `e.ColumnIndex` y `e.RowIndex` usando de la siguiente forma

```
public void DataGridView1_private void DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {

    //obtienes el valor reservado
    string valorCelda = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

    //nombre columna
    string nombrecolumna = DataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;

    //obtienes el valor de la primer columna
    string valorPrimerCelda = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

}
```

para obtener los datos que necesitas